# Dash ImportError: cannot import name 'get_current_traceback' from 'werkzeug.debug.tbtools'

Tags: python, pycharm, conda, plotly-dash

I'm trying to run a simple dash app in a conda environment in Pycharm, however I'm running into the error in the title. Weirdly enough, I couldn't find a place on the internet which has a mention of this bug, except for [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/dash-werkzeug-import-error-when-trying-to-run-dash-plotly-originating-from-werkzeug/45456). The code is simple, as all I'm trying to run is a simple dashapp; code obtained the code from [here](https://dash.plotly.com/layout). I have tried switching between python versions in conda (back and forth between python 3.9, 3.8 and 3.7) but the error seems to be persistent. I know I have also correctly installed all its dependencies as I'm not getting any import error. Would appreciate if anyone could help with this.

Edit: Versions of Dash installed, as requested by @coralvanda :
[image: dash_versions]

Basically, I just did a pip install of everything so all the versions of packages are the latest.

Screenshot of a full traceback of the error:
[image: traceback]

Comment: Would you list out which versions you've installed of your packages? Also, would you copy the full traceback here?

Comment: @coralvanda Just did, added two screenshots.

Comment: If you uninstall all the Dash stuff and reinstall v2.2.0, does it have the same problem? That would be the next thing I'd check

Comment: Tried it, unfortunately that didn't work

Comment: Which version of `werkzeug` is installed? I just had a similar problem with v2.1.0, but it worked when I downgraded to v1.0.1

Comment: @coralvanda I just downgraded to v2.0.3 and now it's working, thank you so much! Omygod so this was the fault of this damn dash library then. Hate it when this happens.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've been in the same problem.

Uninstall the wrong version with:

```bash
pip uninstall werkzeug
```

Install the right one with:

```bash
pip install -v https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/archive/refs/tags/2.0.3.tar.gz
```

Comment: Yep, it just so happened that Werkzeug released a new version on march 28, which I wasn't aware of, so rolling back to the previous version fixed it.

Comment: Why not just upgrade with `pip install -U werkzeug`?

Comment: @CGFoX The new version that Werkzeug released yesterday broke dash and caused that import error. Since dash forces to install the latest version for every one of its dependencies, the latest version of Werkzeug got installed automatically by it.

Answer (score 13):

This is caused by `dash` and fixed in the [new 2.3.1 release](https://github.com/plotly/dash/releases/tag/v2.3.1). So simply do:

```
pip install -U dash
```

If that doesn't help, you have to downgrade `werkzeug` manually, e.g.,

```
pip install werkzeug==2.0.3
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 5):

This problem is not new, it effects Dash well back into the 1.x releases.

Both of the above answers have part of the solution (i.e. the one that worked for me).

It ***is*** a werkzeug error, but it is not enough to upgrade werkzeug for some reason. You must manually uninstall first, and then install the correct version next.

I am using Dash 1.20 and the latest version of werkzeug that worked for me is 2.0.3. So,

```
pip uninstall werkzeug
```

and

```
pip install werkzeug==2.0.3
```

*Note: there must not be any spaces around the `==`.
THIS WILL FAIL : `pip install werkzeug  ==  2.0.3`
THIS WILL work: `pip install werkzeug==2.0.3`*